# Webforms - The right way to navigate using master & content pages without a page refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, master-pages, contentplaceholder

taking in considiration the issue of SEO while designing my web site 
i was trying to create a nice way to navigate between pages

using content place holders within divs as follows

```
[ main div ]
    [Header Div]

                         |------- Top Baner ---------|


    [Body div]
                    [left column]                             || [right column]
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |div1 inside it -> placeholder1 | | div2 -> p.h 2|    ||  |rightMenu|
                                                              ||  |menu item1|
                                                              ||  |menu item2|
        [div3 inside it -> placeholder3 | |[div4 -> p.h 4|    ||  |menu item3|


    [Footer div]
```

the idea was that on menuitem clicked, the 4 squers within Left column will turn into 1 main content div displaying the menu-itemas other content pages.

a theory : the rest of .aspx contents , that the right menu is redirecting to, could have been within the default.aspx page (hidden until clicking on a menu item) though i was thinking of 2 problems:

for starter if i will use all contents of menu-items (.aspx content pages) within default.aspx
... that way, the page will be too heavy to load.

and second is: with SEO in mind,(which also includes the issue of that page load timing) 
but also the idea that my website will only have one .aspx page for its content and i think that it is not good for SEO having only one .aspx page...
so all in all, i guess that's not a good idea to use hidden content on one url/aspx page

take a look at my current home page you will get the idea 
[LINK](http://www.rcl.co.il)

**The question is:** if i want to have:

1) **no page refresh**

2) animation when switching contents, while navigating to other content pages

3) implementing it via using asp.net master vs content pages with `<asp:contentPlaceHolder>`

what would be the approach (taking into account that i need that content to help with SEO...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a [Navigation framework for ASP.NET Web Forms](https://navigation.codeplex.com/) that solves your problem because it helps you to build SEO-friendly Single Page Applications.

Here's [an article with sample code outlining the general approach](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301683/Knockout-Navigation-for-ASP-NET-Web-Forms). I hope this helps.